# Does any known function behaves like flipped hyperbolic-tangent in [x, inf] and as sigmoidal in [-inf, x]?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity, exponential-function, recreational-mathematics

I want to use a transfer function for my simulation which behaves like the **red-curve** on the right [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laAbU.png). I do this by using a flipped hyperbolic-tangent in the range (-intercept, inf] and a sigmoidal in [-inf, intercept]. (please do look at the picture)

This is nice; it looks like what I want.

However, when change the slope parameter, I have to adjust the delta ([A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laAbU.png)), and the peak becomes more...non-symmetrically smooth. I understand that the functions have different curvatures ([B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJZOz.png), [C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCYeU.png)) and will behave differently away from the peak. However, what I want is a smooth peak.

Is there a single continuous function that I can use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

PS. Here's the Python-code if you wanna take a look: *https://pastebin.com/xGWNyUzi*

Comment: I don't think you want that "inverted".

Comment: @J.G. what do you mean by that? It's not readily clear to me.

Comment: $\artanh x$ becomex complex for $x>1$. You want to bound the range of your function on $\Bbb R$, not the domain on which it stays in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I see what you mean by the quotation marks now. Sorry, for the blasphemous language. Does "flipped" sound better? All I do is send `tanh(-x)` instead of `tanh(x)`.

Comment: Note $\tanh(-x)=-\tanh x$.